# Formatting number to decimal

Tags: php

I understand how to format a number from for example 2.10 to 2.1 nut how would i format a number so that `381` -> `38.1%` or `38.1`

Either result is fine as I can just add a percent sign after the first result. I was thinking of maybe splitting the number then adding a decimal after the second number but this wouldn't work with 100%?

Answer (score 2):

If 381 is a percentage of 1000, then 381 divided by 1000 = 0.381
Multiply 0.381 by 100 to get 38.1

The SQL CODE would be:
DECLARE @Number1 Decimal(18,1) = 381, @Number2 Decimal(18,1) = 0

SET @Number2 = CAST(ROUND((@Number1 / 1000) *(100),1,1) AS DECIMAL(18,1))

SELECT @Number2

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Doing `$number = $number / 10;` should turn the trick.

Comment: Gah its been a long day. Thank you.

Comment: Try to change your the voice from "how about" to an [active voice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_voice)

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
$number = 381;
echo sprintf("%02.2f%%", $number/10);
```

Output:

```
38.10%
```

If you don't want it with 2 decimal just change `.2` as you want it